# Regex expression to retrieve all JSONs from a long string

Tags: json, regex

I have a long string with many JSONs inside, it looks like:

```
{"a":"b"}{"c":"d"}{"e":"f"}...
```

I prepared the regex expression to retrieve all JSONs from that kind of string:

```
\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}
```

It works quite good, but there is an one problem with it. If fails when it needs to retrieve a string like this one:

```
{"a":"b"}{"c":"d"}{"e":"f}"}...
```

It assumes, that the "}" sign after the "f" letter ends the third JSON, but if of course doesn't. Do you have guys any idea how can I fix this REGEX?

Code sample:
https://regex101.com/r/L9UUzj/1

Thank you!

Comment: You only have to be more precise than `[^{}]` and to describe separately parts enclosed between quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^{}]` doesn't take in account parts enclosed between quotes, instead you can replace it with: `[^"{}]|"[^"]*"`

You can do it with this pattern:

```
{[^"{}]*+(?:"[^"]*+"[^"{}]*+|(?R)[^"{}]*+)*+}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4E0jX/1)

In addition, if you want to deal with escaped quotes (with a backslash) inside quoted parts:

```
{[^"{}]*+(?:"[^"\\]*+(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"[^"{}]*+|(?R)[^"{}]*+)*+}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4E0jX/2)

These two patterns use an *unrolled* design that is more efficient. In short, instead of writing `(A|B)*`, you write `A*(BA*)*` that needs less steps.

Possessive quantifiers `*+` are here to prevent a lot of backtracking when curly brackets aren't balanced at a position in the string. This way the pattern will fail quickly at this position.

Obviously these two patterns don't fully describe the json syntax. Feel free to do it using named groups and the `(?(DEFINE)...)` feature, it is far from impossible (*). But you can also use the second pattern to extract the json substrings and then to check them with the json parser of your choice.

---

(*) something like this:

```
~
\g<object>

(?(DEFINE)
    (?<string> " [^"\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^"\\]*+ )*+ " )
    (?<table> \[ (?: \s* \g<value> (?: \s* , \s* \g<value> )*+ )? \s* ] )
    (?<object> { 
        (?: \s* \g<key> \s* : \s* \g<value> 
            (?: \s* , \s* \g<key> \s* : \s* \g<value> )*+ 
        )? \s* }
    )
    (?<boolean> [Tt]rue | [Ff]alse )
    (?<number> (?: [0-9]+ (?: \. [0-9]* )? | \.[0-9]+ )
               (?: [Ee] -? [0-9]+ )? )

    (?<key> \g<string> (?<= [^"]" | \\"" ) )
    (?<value> \g<table> | \g<object> | \g<string>
            | \g<number> | \g<boolean> | null )
)
~x
```

Comment: You're great. Thank you!

Comment: Huh - I'd always thought thought "if I handle backslashed quotes, I'll also need to handle backslashed backslashes, and so on infinitely - that feels like an endless rabbithole" - and avoided the topic entirely. But you're right, I only need to always accept the first character after a backslash, whatever it is. Yay! I learned a thing! :D

Comment: @DewiMorgan: well done, few people notices that and continues to write things like `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\"`.